# Angular equivalent of Vue().$mount()

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, dom

I'm creating an app which builds an HTML DOM based on a JSON form. This form is extensible and allows adding custom controls. One important thing is to make it work with different JavaScript frameworks.

What I'm trying is to generate a virtual DOM with Angular, but instead of it being attached to the `document`, I want to have the DOM element within a variable.

This is the way I've managed to do it with Vue:

```
const app = new Vue({
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement(MyCustomControl, {}, this.$slots.default);
    },
    components: { MyCustomControl }
}).$mount();

const customControl = document.createElement("div").appendChild(app);
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Angular?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with Angular, can't you make use of dynamic components instead? https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. Idea would be that you'd create your components dynamically based on the data you get. Similar to dynamic components in Vue.

Comment: The equivalent is `bootstrap()`. You need to provide an element to it. I don't remember if it works fine with detached nodes.

Answer (score 0):

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] // You can modify it here
})
```